# Auto rotate w/background image: How to get rid of tiling effect? Best Practice?

Tags: ios, autorotate

I have this code to change the background image during rotation on the iPad:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{    
if (![SysConfig isPhone]) {   // Only need to worry about this for the iPad 
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    if ([SysConfig isRetina]) {          
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(fromInterfaceOrientation)) {
            [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png"]]];
        } else {
            [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png"]]];
        }
        // retina display above, regular below
    } else {
    \\ Same thing but for low res display            
        }
    }
}
}
```

It works fine, except that for a brief moment you see the original background image tiled on the newly rotated device, then it rotates and shifts to the new image which fits on the new orientation just fine, so it doesn't tile.  I'd like to get rid of the tiling visual effect.

I gather from reading on SO that I might hide the tiling by some sort of animation (cross fade the two images, or shrink the old image and expand it into the new smoothly as the rotation occurs).  But I'm also not sure that I am doing this in the right place, since I've seen approaches that involve `viewDidAppear` `viewWillAppear` `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` etc.

Two questions:

1. Can I avoid this tiling effect by simply moving this code, maybe slightly modified, to a different method (maybe affecting timing of the effect)?
2. If I have to go to a more elaborate animation, which method should I use?  Any pointers to an example?

Thanks.  I've done lots of reading but it seems there are lot of ways to get it almost right, and if someone has a comment on best practice I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: I put the same code, except for exchanging the instances of Portrait and Landscape, into `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` and that fixed the tiling issue.